# Calling external API from inside a cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong

I want to call an external api from inside the cluster so I followed the Kubernetes documentation

as the below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: https://api.github.com/
```

and I was able to get a response with an externalName:

```
externalName: httpbin.org
```

but when I use an http or https end point it fails.

I know that the documentation states the below

```
Warning:

You may have trouble using ExternalName for some common protocols, including HTTP and HTTPS. If you use ExternalName then the hostname used by clients inside your cluster is different from the name that the ExternalName references.

For protocols that use hostnames this difference may lead to errors or unexpected responses. HTTP requests will have a Host: header that the origin server does not recognize; TLS servers will not be able to provide a certificate matching the hostname that the client connected to.
```

But I  want to know how to make http/https calls from inside the cluster to an external API?

Answer (score 0):

**But I want to know how to make http/https calls from inside the cluster to an external API?**

I don't see any reason why don't you just call the external API from the cluster without usage of `ExternalName`. You don't actually need that type of service to do that. Unless there is something that you're not telling us here.

Now moving on towards why you encountered you errors. With `ExternalName` type of service the request with come to your destination with `Host: my-service` which he inherited from the service you created. If we take an example `api.github.com` as you mentioned once try to reach it receives the `http` request with header `Host: my-service` and he does not what do with it nor where to route it. So, if you upfront that you want to use `api.github.com` why don't you just reach it directly?

See here an example that I've made to show the `header` that `ExternalName` injects (I named the service `my-service-test`):

```sh
[root@cent /]# curl my-service-test -v
* About to connect() to my-service-test port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 183.36.108.201...
* Connected to my-service-test (183.36.108.201) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: my-service-test  
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 07:44:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 166
< Connection: close
< X-Proxy-Server: Sparta
< 
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

Nginx received the request but does the `host` header does not match what he expects hence he does not what to do with it.

The workaround for that might to use nginx pod as proxy or perhaps ingress to try to rewrite the header before it reaches the desired target.